# Random sample with lucene 4

Tags: lucene

I am looking any way to get some random sample from my query results.
The thing is that it should preserve the order and it should be repeatable with the same seed.
I was trying with custom Filter but it doesn't have access to all returned docs in one call.
In the worst case I am going to call query take ids, sample from its array and call query once again with additional filter (the thing is that I need it in a few different places, and I have one common method to build a filter)

Do you have any better idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

[RandomSortField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html) does exactly that, so if you need to stay at Lucene level, you could just look at the source code and see how hard is to bundle all java code needed on top of Lucene

Comment: I am sorry but this solution won't work in my case.  RandomSortField is used dor random sorting. But I want to prevent order given by Sort object. Just select n random docs.

Comment: that would be done in Solr by sorting randomly and then asking only for X top docs, so you get the desired behaviour

Comment: No. Because as you have said it would be 'sorted randomly'. But I want to keep the order described by the Sort instance (ie by date)

Comment: ok I see know what you want. This is doable in solr by what I said (to pick the repeatable random set) and then using a reranking on top (to sort by date). But trying to bring so much solr code at that point might not be practical...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by getting all documents, creating a collection of id fields, sampling that array and adding sampled result to filters of main Lucene query. And searching for a results once again.